# Not Receiving HC-05 data

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, hc-05

I've been trying to use this HC-05 bluetooth module for a project, where the data would be sent to a Max/MSP/jitter program. Initially, every time I connected my bluetooth device to my computer, it stayed connected for about 10 to 20 seconds then disconnect. I'm not sure if it's a voltage thing, but from what I read on other forums, it should work fine. My setup:

1- Powering Arduino on a wall wart (Input: 100-240V AC, 50/60Hz 0.3A ; Output: 12V DC 1A);

2- Bluetooth's Tx to Arduino's Rx (D3) and Bluetooth's Rx to Arduino's Tx (D4)

3- APDS9960 sensor also connected on the same breadboard (the sensor I should be receiving the data from, and I do, when connected on an USB cable port)

4 - HC-05 configured to be 115200 baud (AT+UART=115200,0,0), which seems to be the appropriate bps for HC-05 to Max (??)

But then... Once I logged into Max, and printed the data from this serial port (which should send data in a continuous fashion), some lines were printed and then it stopped. So I go on to check the Arduino Serial Monitor and – though everything seemed to be working fine and I received the data properly – there's nothing showing up.

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include <Arduino_APDS9960.h>

SoftwareSerial blue(3,4); //rx tx, qualquer 2 portas digitais sem ser 7 e 8 

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 Serial.begin(115200);
 blue.begin(115200);
 
  Serial.println("mensagem do computador");
  blue.println("mensagem do módulo bluetooth");
  
   if (!APDS.begin()) {
    blue.println("Error initializing APDS9960 sensor.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

    while (! APDS.colorAvailable()) {
    delay(5);
  }
  int r, g, b;

  // read the color
  APDS.readColor(r, g, b);

  // print the values
//  blue.print("r = ");
  blue.println(r);
//  blue.print("g = ");
  blue.println(g);
//  blue.print("b = ");
  blue.println(b);
//  blue.print();

  // wait a bit before reading again
  delay(100);
}
```